# using Protractor to test a dashboard with 2 factor oAuth

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to test my angular application which is basically a dashboard but its behind a 2 factor authenticated security. I can not access my Dashboard without passing that, but protractor starts a new instance every time and It stops me at my 2 factor auth page where I need to enter code I received by text meassage.

I am totally faild to access it, is there any workaroud by which I can start it in my default profile of chrome where I've already logged into my portal? or any other solution which can help me get through 2 factor authentication using Protractor.

Comment: Can you send your 2factor codes to email? You can catch IMAP mails inside protractor with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2

Comment: no, text message is the only option :'(, Its a corporate product and they are using this method in all their applications (30+) they cant simply change it for just one test case.

Comment: Hehe, it is probably an overkill, but resend that sms to email, and then catch it in protractor? : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sms2emailbuddy if you have android. :D